# Minecraft Java: "Connection Lost" after approx 30 seconds of uptime on multiplayer modded server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-mods

(Asking on behalf of my tech-illiterate friend)

I'm able to log into the server, but I can't interact with anything (e.g. place blocks, open chests). After 30 seconds, I'm kicked out with the error message "Connection lost". This has been happening consistently for a week, and only on this specific server. No other players have been affected or have experienced this issue. So far I've tried:

- Restarting the launcher
- Restarting my PC
- Reinstalling all of my mods

But nothing has worked. Any ideas?

ETA: Mod list

- Origins
- Xaero's World Map
- Xaero's Mini Map
- WI Zoom
- wiicustomorigins
- Pehkui
- originsumbrellas
- Origins Classes
- Mob origins
- Hwyla fabric
- Fabric API
- ExtraOrigins
- Environmental armor

Comment: which mods did you install? Which mods does the server support? Which server are you talking about? if it is a personal server, then try asking the host that which mods are installed in the server, and install just those mods.

Comment: That was the first thing we tried. We even got a file drop from a moderator using the exact same mod files they have, and used only those. It's a private server using the Origins mod along with a few others, list is as follows:

- Origins
- Xaero's World Map
- Xaero's Mini Map
- WI Zoom
- wiicustomorigins
- Pehkui
- originsumbrellas
- Origins Classes
- Mob origins
- Hwyla fabric
- Fabric API
- ExtraOrigins
- Environmental armor

Comment: The mod requires fabric loader, and it doesn't seem to be present in your list. Make sure it is present.

Link to fabric loader :
https://www.curseforge.com/linkout?remoteUrl=https%253a%252f%252ffabricmc.net%252f

Answer (score 1):

Add fabric loader to your mods folder, you can download it from [here](https://www.curseforge.com/linkout?remoteUrl=https%253a%252f%252ffabricmc.net%252f). If you check the website of the origins mod, it says you also need the fabric loader mod.

Answer (score 0):

I am having this problem as well, and what I found out that worked was just retrying it many times. There also seems to be a problem with the server as well, as I am not the only one having this problem, so do some others.